# Как красиво вынести из из главного потока ожидание ответа от метода , чтобы не получить ANR

Tags: java, android

Методов   `asyncUploadingData.get();` ждет пока AsyncTask завершит работу и вернет ответ. Всё конечно происходит моментально, но вдруг какие то неполадки с сетью, интернет есть , но очень медленный и тут прилетит ANR. 
   Так то работа итак проходит в отдельном потоке и дополнительно и ожидание выводить в поток бессмысленно, тем более что без этого результата дальнейшее выполнение программы невозможно. 
   Как ждать и не получать ANR? вот так наверно будет звучать правильная постановка вопроса. 
  Вместо AsyncTask ничего другого не предлагать.

```
private void UploadData() {
    String url = "https://api.fixer.io/" + date + "?base=" + CurrentCurrency;
    AsyncUploadingData asyncUploadingData = new AsyncUploadingData();
    asyncUploadingData.execute(url);
    try {
        answer = asyncUploadingData.get(); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

.

```
public class AsyncUploadingData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


private String answer;


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    setAnswer(urls);
    return answer;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
    super.onPostExecute(answer);

}


private void setAnswer(String... urls) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        int code = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf8"));
            answer = "";
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                answer += line;
            }
            reader.close();
        }

        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

. Отправил ссылку на активити сюда, для создания обратного вызова.

```
 interface AsyncResult {
        void getResult(String answer);
    }

    AsyncUploadingData(AsyncResult mCallback) {
        this.mCallback = mCallback;
    }
```

Comment: Переопределяем `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` и выполняем код там, либо делаем оттуда обратный вызов.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Код выполняется в doInBackground() , после onPostExecute() мне возвращается результат. Невозможно написать asyncUploadingData.get() в onPostExecute() , так как asyncUploadingData и есть экземпляр AsyncTask . и метод get писал не я , это метод самого AsyncTask.

Comment: Ну а если обратный вызов, подключу я интерфейс и снова буду ждать  в главном потоке , когда же обратный вызов сработает. А он 5 сек не срабатывает и привет ANR

Comment: А вы что потом делаете с `answer` полученным из `asyncUploadingData.get()`?

Comment: Парсюю) в подготовленный класс с методами, из этого класса беру массив и отображаю в ListView. Короче говоря я этот файл скачиваю по сети и следом отображаю.

Comment: я вот смотрю для потоков есть метод join(), ожидающий выполнение. или IsAlive..

Comment: `get()` вызывать не нужно - результат приходит параметром в `onPostExecute()`

Comment: woesss, именно. Метод UploadData() это метод в совершенно другом классе. Не в классе AsyncTask.  И чтобы получить параметр от onPostExecute() используется метод AsyncTask.get() .  Иначе как мне еще получить результат, если не из третьего параметра AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

Comment: Вот прикрепил класс asyncTaskA . метод  UploadData() вызывается из класса Main из основного потока

Comment: Вот поэтому и используют `Callback` - передаёте его в асинк с конструктором и в `onPostExecute()` вызываете типа: `callback.onResult(result)`

Comment: И пока я буду ждать callback.onResult(result)  главный поток  у меня не выдаст ANR , хоть результат придется 10 сек ждать?

Comment: Нет, Вы не ждёте результат - главный поток продолжает работу, а когда асинк отработает, то "вклинится" в него через очередь событий, как, например, нажатие кнопки - поток ведь не стоит в ожидании нажатия.

Comment: ААА..Просто я не могу продолжать выполнение кода, пока не получу ответ. Значит мне надо сделать так ,чтобы после срабатывая калбека , прошли вызовы остальных методов, которые ждали ответ. Спасибо

Comment: Да, именно так!

Comment: woesss , я решил вопрос использовав обратный вызов, а для этого я в конструктор передал ссылку на активити, код я приложил. Но теам лид указал на минус, сказав , что я передал ссылку на активити. Почему это плохо, как этого можно было избежать? Нужно было просто переопределить AsyncTask.onPostExecute() ? как переопределить, чтобы из него получить ответ я не понял, прикрепить код пожалуйста как ответ. Вы в принципе на вопрос в комментариях ответили и этот код как дополнение.  И можно помечать как ответ. Спасибо